# Unity Freezes When I Press The Play Button With The Instantiate Syntax C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

Every time I press the play button in unity it just sits there doing nothing and I think it has something to do with the Instantiate Syntax here is my code and this is the only script I have running. I'm trying to just simply make a grid of my GameObject. if anyone knows why that would be great or if not maybe you know a better way to do it. Thanks!!

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class Script2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Sprite;

    void Start()
    {
        Generate();
    }
    public void Generate()
    {
        float width = Sprite.transform.lossyScale.x;
        float height = Sprite.transform.lossyScale.y; 
        for (int y = 0; y <= 100; y += 10)
        {
           for (int x = 0; x <= 100; y += 10)
            {
                GameObject Square = Sprite;
                Instantiate(Square, new Vector2(x * width, y * height), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int x = 0; x <= 100; y += 10)` should be `for (int x = 0; x <= 100; x += 10)` .. I suspect a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your x loop has an error, so it ran into infinite loop.
Should be x+=10

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 100; x += 10)
{
    GameObject Square = Sprite;
    Instantiate(Square, new Vector2(x * width, y * height), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked I'm new to programming so I suspect this will happen a lot more but none the less thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have is the method I use when creating a grid of prefabs which is this method

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Class1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Prefab;

    private void Start ()
    {

        Generate ();

    }

    public void Generate ()
    {

        float width = Prefab.transform.lossyScale.x;
        float height = Prefab.transform.lossyScale.y;

        for ( int y = 0; y < 100; y++ )
        {

            for ( int x = 0; x < 100; x++ )
            {

                Vector3 position = new Vector3 ( x * width, y * height );

                Instantiate<GameObject> ( Prefab, position, Quaternion.identity );

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Note that `lossyScale` not necessarily equal to object width ... would be more secure using e.g. `Renderer.bounds`. Also note that OP creates 10 * 10 objects while you are creating 100 * 100 ;)

Comment: thankyou although the other person figured out my error this worked to and ill probably use some of your code thanks for the help

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for the note, I must of misread the numbers while reading the question, I need to be more careful when reading.